# how can I show the default table content as different and when click on button table content should be different in the same table in the UI?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a code to display users and I have a delete button for deleting user. When I delete any user, the deleted user will be removed from the user list. In the above I have two buttons one is for create user, and another is to show all deleted user. How can I show the deleted user when I click on "View Deleted User" button in the same below table where it was showing all the users.

[image]

Here below is the code

```
<body class="back-color">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <h2><b>Manage Users</b></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">info</i> <span>View Deleted Users</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <a href="crtusr.php" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Add New User</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            if($no_of_users>1){
                echo '<table class="paginated table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Role</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';

                    while($userdetails = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                       echo' <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>'.$userdetails['username'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$userdetails['email'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$userdetails['role'].'</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <a href="" class="delete" name="delete" data-toggle="modal" Onclick="return ConfirmDelete()"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
                        }
                    echo '</tbody>
                </table>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a soft delete option,

Steps:

1. Create a field is_deleted, a boolean true if user is deleted and
   false if not which is false by default, in your users table.
2. Now on Delete button's click make the is_deleted true.
3. To list only undeleted users, query the table with condition
   is_deleted => false.
4. To list deleted users, query the table with condition is_deleted => true.
5. You can also give option for hard delete, which deletes user from table.

   You should do like,

   ```
   //if retrieving undeleted users from table 
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users from is_deleted = 0";

   //else retrieving deleted users from table 
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users from is_deleted = 1";

   //$con holding your database connection details 
   $user_details= mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   while($userdetails = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // $userdetails array contains the data of a user
        // iterate it and fill your table accordingly
   }
   ```

Hope this works.

Comment: Yeah I have did the same, And I have query as well. but how can I display the deleted user details in the same table on UI @Ved

Comment: I think the query which is retrieving the data from table needs to be modified every time,